# How do I locally increase the amount of a global variable?

Tags: python, global-variables, pyqt4

I'm writing a program using PyQt and I'm trying to figure out a way to keep adding to a global variable every time a particular button is clicked. This way if my global is 0 then the third time the button is clicked my global would equal 3. Here's the relevant code.

```
# from the main window class

QtCore.QObject.connect(self.pushButton_17, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.CadDraw)

def CadDraw(self):
    myGlobal +=1 #the previous value from the last time CadDraw was called plus 1
    DoStuff()
```

This is pretty easy in C but I'm completely blanking on the python method which I seem to recall was very similiar.

Comment: In general, its better not to use a global variable. Instead, store the value on object (perhaps the self that you have there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the global statement

```
global myGlobal
myGlobal = 0
def CadDraw(self):
    global myGlobal
    myGlobal +=1 [the previous value from the last time CadDraw was called plus 1]
    DoStuff()
```

Comment: Thanks Cedric. That's actually what I was already doing but I had a typo elsewhere that was causing a local and a global variable to share the same name. I didn't realize it until I read your post. Fixed

Comment: fine if i help finding a typo :) That's probably why the use of global variables is dangerous